# c++ jsoncpp Reading json file

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I m new on json, I trying to read my json file from this tutorial site
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JsonCpp

however I get some linker error

1>------ Build started: Project: TwilightAdventure, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>     Creating library C:\Users\MinTeckNG\Desktop\TwilightAdventure\Debug\TwilightAdventure.lib and object C:\Users\MinTeckNG\Desktop\TwilightAdventure\Debug\TwilightAdventure.exp
1>LoadingMap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Json::Reader::Reader(void)" (??0Reader@Json@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall LoadingMap::ReadJsonFileTest(void)" (?ReadJsonFileTest@LoadingMap@@QAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\MinTeckNG\Desktop\TwilightAdventure\Debug\TwilightAdventure.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJJfg.png)
lnk2019 unresolved external symbol

[my json file going to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxgHQ.png)

```
{
"actors": [
    {
        "name": "Ground",
        "pos": {
            "x": 2592.0,
            "y": 96.0
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Grass",
        "pos": {
            "x": 2656.0,
            "y": 96.0
        }
    }
 }
```

my code

```
#include "LoadingMap.h"
#include <fstream>

LoadingMap::LoadingMap(void)
{
}

LoadingMap::~LoadingMap(void)
{
 }

/*const char *LoadingMap::GetFileName(int stage, int difficulties)
 {
char a = '0';
const char *ptr = &a;
return ptr;
 }*/
 /*void LoadingMap::ReadJsonFile(const char *filename)
 {

    }*/

     void LoadingMap::ReadJsonFileTest()
      {
std::ifstream ifs("1-1-0.json");
Json::Reader reader;
//Json::Value obj;
//reader.parse(ifs, obj); 
//std::cout << "Object type: " << obj["name"].asString() << std::endl;

//const Json::Value& pos = obj["pos"]; 

//std::cout << " x: " << pos[0]["x"].asUInt();
//std::cout << " y: " << pos[1]["y"].asUInt();

    }
```

my header file

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <json/json.h>

class LoadingMap
{
public:
LoadingMap(void);
~LoadingMap(void);

//const char *GetFileName(int stage, int difficulties);
//void ReadJsonFile(const char *filename);
void ReadJsonFileTest();
 private:

 };
```

well the code is mainly nothing , nothing implement yet, all I try to follow the tutorial and modify .

Comment: Please post the linker error, remove the unneeded comments and poste the whole LoadingMap Code

Comment: Copy the text of the error message from the Output Tab. Its in a format that should make it easy to copy and paste into your question.

Comment: the error picture link, show my visual studio error

Comment: At stackoverflow pictures of text are not welcome because what happens to the picture 2 years from now? The idea of a question is not to help 1 person but people years from now. Also a picture of text is not easily searched when the actual text is easy to see and search.

Comment: but I can't copy the link error description

Comment: It's very simple: You haven't linked to your dependency Json::Reader.

Comment: I did #include <json/json.h> at my .h file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Including a header file is usually not linking a library. I say usually because MSVC does have a way to force linker settings using a #pragma.

Answer (score 0):

changed to rapidjson instead jsoncpp. everything seem ok for now.